# ValueError: too many values to unpack in Flask-wtf

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm using `wtforms-sqlalchemy` extension to query on database and show the result to the user with a nice drop-down list inside a Flask driven web application.

The problem is I tried to get the content and show them on front-end side, But it does not matter how I want to get them it shows constantly below error message:

`ValueError: too many values to unpack`

code for form I haved used: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/94QKgWdNT9/

My model: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JrRbX263pd/

Client side code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Q3rfgNpbdN/

Comment: Thanks, but that does solve my problem. I think there is something wrong with the query. It's not about dictionary stuff.

Comment: Try using SelectField..

    `buyer = SelectField(coerce=int, choices=[(int(person.id), person.username) for person in PersonModel.query.all()])`

Comment: Thanks there is a bug in that module (I think), but at the moment, if you use `wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields` that works completely right. Actually I want to know what's wrong with that.